# addClass breaks JS

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    let menu = document.querySelector(' #menu-mainmenu ');
    menu.style.display = 'none';
});

let newButton = document.createElement(' div ');
```

This code didn't cause any problem.

The moment I've added the following code right under the let `newButton`, suddenly, as it seems, the JS broke (no JS would load properly anywhere in the site).

```
newButton.className = 'menuButton';
```

Console returns this error:

> Uncaught DOMException:
>
> Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document':
>
> The tag name provided (' div ') is not a valid name.

Why would this happen? What is the problem with creating a `div` element this way?

Comment: remove the spaces around `div`

Comment: which browser? because your original code results in an error before that line is added

Answer (score 1):

You have extra spaces around the `div` tag and that cause an error. Remove them

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    //let menu = document.querySelector(' #menu-mainmenu ');
    //menu.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('Worked !!!');
});

let newButton = document.createElement('div');
newButton.className = 'menuButton';
```